# retrieve data from json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

JSON:

```
 var obj = {
"USA": {
  "Latitude": 37.0902,
  "Longitude": 95.7129
},
"Japan": {
  "Latitude": 36.2048,
  "Longitude": 138.2529
}
 }
```

How do i retrieve country , latitude and longitude data from the json and then store them in different array(countryArr , latArr , longArr)

Comment: you should add a console.log(obj) in your browser to check how the object look like :)

Comment: 1) That's not JSON. 2) What have you tried so far?

Comment: and if it was json, just a quick look on Google may help : http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_parse

Answer (score 2):

This is really a very simple question. Perhaps read up here - http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/introduction.php

```
var a = obj.USA.Latitude;
alert(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) JSON you can use `map()` and `forEach()` to return desired result.

```js
var obj = {"USA":{"Latitude":37.0902,"Longitude":95.7129},"Japan":{"Latitude":36.2048,"Longitude":138.2529}}

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(e) {
  var ar = [e];
  Object.keys(obj[e]).forEach(function(el) {
    ar.push(obj[e][el]);
  });
  return ar;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why? It is already in a usable array:

```
obj.Japan.Latitude;
```

But if you really need it:

```
var countries = []; var lats = []; var longits = [];
for (var b in obj) {
    countries.push(b)
    lats.push(obj[b].Latitude);
    longits.push(obj[b].Longitude);
}
```

Now the three arrays have your values.